# I'm trying to making a button have to two actions. Send data to a Mailchimp and then send the user to another page

Tags: html, css

I have a form that when a customer fills it in, the data gets sent to Mailchimp when the button gets clicked. After this process id like the customer to get sent over to a thank you page to download a PDF document. Can a button have to actions like this?​

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just need to use e.PreventDefault() function, so it does not refresh the page until you complete all your tasks. Just add an EventListener to the button.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", sentEmailsAndRedirect); 


function sentEmailsAndRedirect(e){
 e.preventDefault()

sendMailChimp():
donwloadPdf();
window.location.href = "http://www.page.com";
}
```